# Python - convert AAF to XML and read metadata for the audio used

Tags: python, xml

I am doing some project that's accepting advanced authority files (AAF) as an input and extracting all the metadata for the audio files that's been used in this aaf file. So what I've done so far is, I've used [pyaaf python binding](http://markreidvfx.github.io/pyaaf/) to convert the AAF into XML.

I did not find any documentation for these XML files. With my common sense, I was able to extract the tracks(audio files) used in the aaf file along with the duration too.

What I want to achieve now is, I want the exact position of the audio that's been placed in the project.

For example, [For this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0m8v.png) ( aaf file viewed in Avid Media Composer), there are number of audio files being used but in different positions. I want to know the exact position of each audio file.

P.S. Are there any other ways rather than converting aaf to xml using pyaaf and reading the metadata more easily?

EDIT: Okay, as a workaround, I managed to use EDL files rather than aaf files.